# IIS Handler Mappings for classic asp page include(.inc) file

Tags: asp-classic, include

I am mirgranting a classic ASP site to newer version of Windows server hosted in IIS 10.

When loading the default.asp page, I found in the browser's developer tool, network tab it says helpers.inc file could not be find. But it is in the same folder with the default page.

The helpers.inc file is invoked in the default.asp page by this code:

```
<script src="helpers.inc" language="VBScript" defer="true"></script>
```

If I try to access the helpers.inc file from browser, I will get this error:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Most likely causes:
•It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all content.
•The feature you are trying to use may not be installed.
•The appropriate MIME map is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.)
•If ASP.NET is not installed.
```

I tried add a handler mapping for *.inc file using the %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll executable, but it doesn't seem working. Gives me a new error:

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Most likely causes:
•The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler.
```

I am wondering what I need to let the include(.inc) file can be recognized/read by the asp page?

Comment: My understanding (and I may be wrong) is that .inc files are treated as just regular text files and are intended more for template integration rather than as pages that contain asp code, although VBscript contained within a .inc file will still execute if included within an asp page. They're certainly not treated the same as .asp files by IIS as default. I've always avoided using them as I've never really seen the point (infact, they seem quite dangerous). Check what's contained within your .inc files first, but just adding a MIME Type might be all you need to do.

Comment: @Adam, it's just VBScript functions. I tried if I copy the code within the helpers.inc into the script tag, the page just load properly. Sorry not familiar with handler mapping, you mentioned adding a MIME Type, is it in IIS, click the website/application->MIME types-> add a new MIME Type there? If yes, what's MIME type I should use in here? text/plain? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd probably wait for someone else to comment, as I'm not 100% sure about inc files. But yes text/plain would be the MIME type I'd use. However, just to reiterate; if your inc files are in a public directory their source code will be exposed.

Comment: If it's just VB functions, why not use <!--#include-->? I manage an ancient classic ASP app, and that is how the VB functions are loaded for that.

Comment: That script tag doesn't include `runat="server"` so Classic ASP will never run it, it will be ignored by modern browsers on the client-side because it's VBScript which is only supported by old IE. The reason IIS blocks it is because `.inc` won't be defined in your IIS mime type mappings.

Comment: @Julie the OP didn't say they added it, they said *"The helpers.inc file is invoked in the default.asp page by this code:"*. Need the OP to clarify whether they have changed the migrated code or it's "as is" from the migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS 7.5 doesn't run \*.inc as ASP Classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907506/iis-7-5-doesnt-run-inc-as-asp-classic)

Comment: Reading the duplicate question @Lankymart posted it looks like setting a mime mapping is a bad idea for inc files, as they're obviously not intended to be served directly by IIS. Which makes a lot of sense. The error message you received was correct, IIS should be preventing you from loading an inc file over HTTP. The problem is you're not including them correctly (as already answered). No mime mapping is required for using inc files as SSI.

Comment: Xiao, are you looking at this website in Internet Explorer? If it is client-side code, and you're using Chrome, it's not going to work, I don't think, because client-side ASP requires Internet Explorer, so far as I know.

Comment: @Julie yes but Chrome won't return `404.3`, that is because [the MIME type hasn't been mapped in IIS](https://serverfault.com/a/281248/199051). There is also no such thing as *"client-side ASP"*, it uses VBScript as its default engine for server-side scripting so the only thing that can be *"client-side"* is VBScript *(which then means you are limited to older IE Internet Browsers)*.

Comment: @Julie, I found there are some code close to the top of the asp page using #include like <!-- #include virtual="/AdminCommon.asp" -->, after the <head> tag and before this <script> and <body> tag. I tried if I did the same way to include the VBScript, the contents will get rendered and displayed on the page.

Comment: @Lankymart, I agree it is a duplicated question as the one asked by su27k back in 2010. Sorry, I am not familiar with classic ASP, didn't realize adding MIME mapping in IIS would expose the source code. I just tried on current live version, it seems having the mapping, so anyone knows the path of the helpers.inc file could view it from IE.

Comment: @Adam, adding MIME mapping in IIS "fixed" my issue and it seems it's the original approach by the author. It is an internal application, I know it won't make much difference it terms of security. Just for my curiosity, what I could do to fix this bad approach by using <include>, but not display the source code on the asp page? The existing <include> tags for other asp page are placed between <head> and <body>. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this line is how it appears in the migrated code *(without any modification)*

```
<script src="helpers.inc" language="VBScript" defer="true"></script>
```

then one thing is clear.

**This isn't a SSI *(Server Side Include)*.**

The tag defines a file with an `.inc` extension as a **Client Side** VBScript. At the moment though, you haven't told IIS that `.inc` is a file type it is allowed to serve as `text/vbscript`.

> **Note:** Having client-side VBScript defined in the page will severely limited cross browser compatability because VBScript is only supported in [older versions of Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532816/692942).

---

#### Why `404.3`?

The reason for the `404.3` is because [IIS blocks unknown file types](https://serverfault.com/a/281248/199051). To fix this you need to add a MIME type mapping in IIS which I wouldn't usually recommend as [`.inc` is sometimes used as an extension for SSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907544/692942), but as we have debunked that theory mapping the MIME type is the way go.

---

#### Why it's not an SSI

There are only three ways to run server-side script in a Classic ASP page;

1. Using processor tags

   ```
   <%
       ...
   %>
   ```
2. Using script tags with the `runat="server"` attribute.

   ```
   <script language="VBScript" runat="server">
       ...
   </script>
   ```
3. Adding an SSI using the `#include` directive.

   ```
   <!-- #include virtual = "somefile.asp" -->
   ```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Answer to IIS 7.5 doesn't run *.inc as ASP Classic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907544/692942) *(argument for not using `.inc` extension for client-side script)*.
- [Answer to difference between mime types and extension filtering on IIS?](https://serverfault.com/a/281248/199051).

Comment: Then what do you suggest he do to fix his problem?

Comment: @Julie it depends on what the `.inc` file is. If it contains server-side script *(either processor tags or server-side script tags)* then it shouldn't be accessed directly so the `404.17` is the correct behaviour and the OP needs to use `#include` syntax to allow it to run inside the ASP page. If it doesn't, then the OP needs to add a MIME type mapping for `.inc` or it will continue to return `404.3` which is the default behaviour for unmapped file types. But like I've said already if that script tag the OP provided is "as-is" from the migrated web application then it can't be an SSI.

Comment: @Lankymart, sorry, didn't notice the answer until I finished replying everyone's comments above. Great answer. I tried the 3rd approach you listed, now the asp page display all the functions source code which is in the Helpers.asp page I created with all the contents copied from Helpers.inc. Not sure if I need to remove the MIME mapping I added before?

Comment: @XiaoHan if you are confident it is meant to be a server-side include than yes remove the MIME Type mapping or you will expose server-side code to the client.

Comment: @Lankymart, I did some try and error, realize it is for client side, the code is actually invoked by other VBscript code on the page. I guess it is a bad implementation. Basically the code is to load data into the page drop down list from database.

Comment: @XiaoHan sounds sketchy. Well, hope this was helpful.

Comment: @XiaoHan, if it is client-side code then there isn't anything odd about it being exposed. They're just using vbscript instead of javascript, old IE-style. And just like you can load javascript up in your browser to see what was done, you can save off client-side VBS.

Comment: (Though I might just go ahead and rewrite it in javascript.)

Answer (score 1):

Include works, but Lankymart's answer is correct.

I created a helpers.inc file:

```
Sub MakeAMsg(MsgText)
    MsgBox MsgText
End Sub
```

I used Include and kept the .inc extension:

```
<script language=VBS>
<!--#include file=helpers.inc-->
makeamsg("This Used Include")
</script>
```

It works. I renamed the .inc with a VBS extension:

```
<SCRIPT language=VBS src=helpers.vbs></SCRIPT>
<script language=VBS>
makeamsg("This Used Script tags with vbs extension")
</script>
```

And that works, too.

I checked my server and by default .vbs was set to a mimetype of text/vbscript. (I'm in the middle of setting up another where I haven't changed anything, and it has this mapping, as well.)

So using #include *does* work, but either changing the extension to .vbs or adding a mimetype that duplicates the .vbs mime type would be better.

Comment: Is `language=vbs` an acceptable identifier for client-side VBScript?

Comment: `.vb` files, you talking about ASP.Net using VB.Net? SSI are an IIS feature that allow server-side scripts to be included in a Classic ASP page. Usually they just use `.asp` extension *(as that is the default handler mapping extension)* but sometimes they are renamed `.ssi` or `.inc` to denote they are intended to be `#include` files. However I don't think this is an SSI because the script tag can't be used like that to call a server-side script.

Comment: @Lankymart yes it is a valid alias for VBScript on both client and server side. JScript is even worse. `ECMAScript`, `JavaScript`, `JavaScript1.1`, `JavaScript1.2`, `JavaScript1.3`, `LiveScript` all points to `JScript` :/

Comment: @Lankymart Works in the app that we have as written and I have never changed it.

Comment: @Lankymart .vb files are what the people who wrote the classic asp app we are using, and they work fine. And re: script tags, that is why I added the addendum about client side VB to my post. But if it is client-side VB, it's not going to work in anything except IE. But the website app that I maintain, they rarely use script tags, whether server-side or client-side, and just use includes, which works. It may not be best practice or anything, but this is classic ASP and best practice would be to rewrite it in something else. lol. Wish I could. :)

Comment: I wonder - could it be that he is just looking at it in something that doesn't accept client-side VB, e.g. non-IE?

Comment: @Julie entirely possible but regardless if they haven't mapped the MIME type in IIS it will continue to return `404.3` anyway.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I wasn't sure as I always used `VBScript` or `JScript`. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if you're using a file as a server side include it doesn't matter what the file extension is, IIS will parse it as if it's part of the page in which it is included. The .inc extension is just a convention to identify it to coders as an include file.